# facebook php sdk: get friends username

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've this code for get all my friends name:

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

$user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends', 'GET');
$friend_array = $user_friends['data'];
foreach ($friend_array as $current) {
   echo($current['name']."<br>");
}
```

but there's a way to get also friends facebook usernames (if they have it)?

Comment: have you tried `print_r` for `user data array` ??
see which fields are retrieved there...

Comment: with ptint_r i get, for each friend, only complete name and id

Comment: have you gone through `permissions` in facebook graph api???

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: With the basic info(default) i should access to field i need, but i can't get usernames! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-basic-info

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your API call to include the username field:

```
$user_friends = $facebook->api( '/me/friends', 'GET', array( 'fields' => 'name,username' ) );
$friend_array = $user_friends['data'];
foreach ( $friend_array as $current ) {
   print_r( $current );
}
```

You can add other values to the `field` attribute too, like location, date of birth etc.

The output will now include the friend's ID, Name and Username (if they have one):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "John Smith", 
      "username": "john.smith", 
      "id": "1234"
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```